# Strict-Sense Stationary Random Process that's not Reversible

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I'm trying to come up with an example of a strict-sense stationary random process that is not reversible.

We define reversible to be if its finite dimensional distributions have the property that $F_{0,k}(t_0, \ldots, t_k) = F_{m,m+k}(t_k, \ldots t_0)$ and strict-sense stationary to be that $F_{m, m+k}(t_0, \ldots t_k) = F_{0,k}(t_0, \ldots, t_k)$ for all integers $m$ and $k$ greater than or equal to 1 and for all values of $t_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

Obviously the definitions are very similar, so in essence I'm looking for a strictly stationary distribution such that $F_{m,m+k}(t_k, \ldots t_0) \neq F_{m, m+k}(t_0, \ldots t_k)$, else we'd be fine. I know that I can't pick a Gaussian wide sense stationary process, as it will be both strict sense stationary and reversible.

Any hints or help would be much appreciated.